# Webpack bundled JS not being executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

This is a very strange problem because actually, *some* of the bundled code is being executed.  I use style loader for my CSS and that of course gets put into `bundle.js` and loads and works fine.  However, I also have a file with some code to set up the jQuery localScroll plugin, and that code isn't working.

To test it, I included in the same file a call to `console.log()`, just telling it to write the number 4.  If I open up `bundle.js`, I can see the `console.log()` call as well as the call to `$.localScroll()`, they just simply aren't running.  Calling `$.localScroll()` manually from the console works as intended.

Here is the JS file in question:

```
console.log(4);
$(() => {
  $.localScroll({duration: 800});
});
```

Here is my Webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './webpack-entry.js',
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
  ],
  output: {
    filename: './javascripts/bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 8192,
            fallback: 'file-loader',
            name: './images/[hash].[ext]'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name(file) {
                if(new RegExp(/partials/).test(file)) {
                  return './views/partials/[name].[ext]'
                }
                return './views/[name].[ext]'
              }
            }
          },
          'pug-asset-loader?root=./src'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['env'],
            }
          },
        ]
      }
    ],
  }
};
```

Finally, here is `bundle.js` (my custom code seems to be at the very bottom, in some sort of array of functions).  The non-uglified version is too long for SO, so here it is on Hastebin: https://hastebin.com/vululimupi.js

Comment: Your problem might be that you're using the file with console.log as a module. It doesn't follow any module specification I've seen. You likely need to define it with any of the [formats supported](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/modules/#what-is-a-webpack-module). It's also likely that you need to export this in entry point and call it from there.

Comment: @uKolka I fiddled with this advice and found that, for whatever reason, changing the `require.context()` in the entry file to a direct `require()` of the specific file makes it work.  The part of the bundled code that contains my JS file doesn't look any different to me, so I'm not sure why that's the case, but it works.  Thank you!

Comment: that's the case bc like any other bundler it relies on JS modularity.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't defined this dependency as a module. Rewriting it following supported module [format specs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/modules/#what-is-a-webpack-module) should help.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, it seems that the essential problem is just as @uKolka was saying - my files were not getting required as modules.  While I'm still not entirely certain why their code was still appearing in my bundle file but not running, I *have* found a way to still reap the recursive benefits of `require.context()`.  It seems that `require.context()` returns a function which is itself capable of resolving the files it logs in whatever folder you have pointed it at.  It also has a member function `keys()` which quite conveniently returns each dependent file name and is easily used with `forEach()`.

Given all that, this is how my `webpack-entry.js` looks now:

```
import './src/stylesheets/scss/master.scss';
require.context('./src/views', true, /\.pug$/);
const js = require.context('./src/javascripts/', false, /\.js$/);

js.keys().forEach(key => js(key));
```

This works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to Babel and React. If you use React, then try to call `./src/index.js` directly and use `"@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"` in your .babelrc. You can take a look at my gist. and in your webpack.config.js:

```
{
    test: /\.js?$/,
    use: ["babel-loader"],
    exclude: /node_modules/
  },
```

take a look at the gist:
 https://gist.github.com/Nagibaba/14e898d99a4be89b00a60d28abc19bc0

Answer (score 0):

*For ruby's rails/webpacker users only*.

This question title and content made me find it before [this issue](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/2955) which may be the correct answers for some users here. To avoid link rot, I'll explain it shortly below:

**Make sure your `@rails/webpacker` npm library and `webpacker` gem both have the same exact version.**

I ended up doing:

```rb
IO.foreach("package.json").find { |line| line[%r("@rails/webpacker": "(.*?)")]}
gem "webpacker", Regexp.last_match(1).tr("-", ".")
```